# Android: button with a part of it having a background

Tags: android

In android is there a mechanism by which a part of the button can have a background picture. [image]

What I need is something like shown in the picture below (A white button which match the parent's width with a picture taking a part of the button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Button XML
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourimage"

Answer (score 0):

You can set background to whole button but if you want to show icon like above, then there is drawableLeft,drawableTo,drawableBottom,drawableRight properties in xml.

```
<Button
    ...
    ...
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_drawable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use :

XML :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
android:text="@string/confirm_title"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="15dip"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/left_icon"
android:drawablePadding="2dip"
android:gravity="center" />
```

Java Code :

```
    btnRegisterMa.setCompoundDrawables(leftDrawable, topDrawable, rightDrawable, bottomDrawable); // can be null
    // Or
    btnRegisterMa.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.left_icon, R.drawable.topt_icon, R.drawable.right_icon, R.drawable.botton_icon); // use zero to null
    // Drawable Padding
    btnRegisterMa.setCompoundDrawablePadding(drawable_padding_intm);
```